# What is the effect of Piety commandement?

Tags: seven-deadly-sins

I've been watching the seven deadly sins for some time now and in recent episodes (trying to avoid spoilers) there's a request for Zeldris to release people under de Piety commandement.

My question is, what are the effects of such commandement?

We've seen people turn to stone for not abiding to a commandement, etc...

Comment: You must have skipped something, the effect of Piety is demonstrated before that request. Although I think it was indeed a fast explanation - a few seconds only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As read on the [wiki article on commandments](https://nanatsu-no-taizai.fandom.com/wiki/Commandment)

> Piety「敬神 Keishin」
>   Anyone who shows their back to the wielder will become an obedient slave of the Demon King and by extension, his representative and youngest son, Zeldris.